# Recieving wrong output in my python linear search program

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-search

i have just made a simple linear search program in python3..
but somehow it is working strangely..idk why?

here is my code :

```
def linear_Search(Transaction_list,n,amount):

for i in range(0,n)::
    if (Transaction_list[i] ==amount):
        return i
    else:
        return -1

n=int(input("Enter the total number of days\n"))
Transaction_list=list(map(int,input(f"Enter all {n} Transactions made each day seperated by spaces :").strip().split()))[:n]
amount=int(input("Enter the Amount u want to search :"))
result=linear_Search(Transaction_list,n,amount)

if (result==-1):
   print(f"Transaction of ${amount} is not made in last {n} days")
else:
   print(f"Transaction of ${amount} is made on day {result+1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return -1` until you have searched through the ENTIRE list.  Right now, you just check the first item and fail if not present.  You  never check the rest of the list.

Also, `i` will be the VALUE of the element, not the INDEX.  You can use `enumerate` to solve that:

```
def linear_Search(Transaction_list,n,amount):
    for n,i in enumerate(Transaction_list):
        if i == amount:
            return n
    return -1
```

Or, since Python has this ability built-in:

```
def linear_Search(Transaction_list,n,amount):
    if amount in Transaction_list:
        return Transaction_list.index(amount)
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
def linear_search(transaction_list, n, amount):
    for i in range(n):
        if (transaction_list[i] == amount):
            return i
    return -1
```